# FedEx Soap v10 - Scheme/XML Issue

Tags: xml, perl, fedex

Currently receiving this when trying to submit my XML to FedEx's servers:

```
    'errorCode' => '5',
'reason' => 'Schema validation failed for request.',
'details' => {
    'ValidationFailureDetail' => {
    'xmlLocation' => {
        'NumberOfPieces' => ''
    },{
        'Units' => ''
    },{
        'Value' => ''
    },
    'message' => {
        'Invalid decimal value: expected at least one digit',
        'string value \'\' is not a valid enumeration value for WeightUnits in namespace http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10',
        'Invalid decimal value: expected at least one digit'
    }
```

Do you folks have any suggestions? It seems Fedex isn't receiving out 'Commodities' array but everything is being set (including the NumberOfPieces', 'Units' & ' Value').

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using '', try '0' (e.g., 'NumberOfPieces' => '0')

Comment: @Scavokovich All of those variables are defined and are not empty or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the entire scheme was different, and oddly enough WeightUnits was not in the new schema that was accepted, as per FedEx, WeightUnits is taken from Weight { units:0 }

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your XML or your schema, how am I supposed to tell you why the XML is invalid against the schema? The message is pretty clear: it says there is something called WeightUnits that should be a decimal value but is actually an empty string.

Comment: Example XML here.. http://jsfiddle.net/NWRWE/ The values are being send over, it just seems they're not being received. Here's what the values being sent are .. http://jsfiddle.net/477Kj/

Comment: Ditto what Mr. Kay said; you're missing element 'WeightUnits'. ('Weight' is a separate element.) I'm referring to FedEx's xml_transguide.pdf from June '05, page 21 of 295, available from their website.

Comment: P. 28 of said file has this: `<WeightUnits>LBS</WeightUnits>
<Weight>10.0</Weight>`